# angularjs pass anonymous function through ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anonymous-function

I am using AngularJS and would like to pass an anonymous JavaScript function from an html element's `ng-click` function as a parameter to a function on my scope.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      <button ng-click="test(function(){alert('pushed');})">Push Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then in JavaScript:

```
function Ctrl1($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(callback){
        callback();
    };
}
```

I have setup up a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/C4t4LystX/gUj8x/4/

---

Whenever I try and do this in my code I get this type of error in the console:

`Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)]`

How should I perform this?

Comment: This is not supported in AngularJS, functions should be defined on a scope before being used in a template. What are you trying to do, functionally speaking?

Comment: Basically I have a directive that handles popups and has an isolated scope and when the popup is closed it emits an event up to a higher level scope that closes the dialog and calls a callback function. The callback function is different depending on which popup is closing, thus my need for a callback function being passed in from the html. This way my directive can stay generic and handle popups of any type, seeing as the callback is defined in the html and not in the directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you'd want to evaluate the function that you would like to run. In this case, if you'd like to execute the instructions `alert("pushed")` then you'd want to evaluate that string.

I've developed a JS Fiddle that does this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gUj8x/6/

Note that the instruction is now passed to Angular as an quote-escaped string.

Comment: Thanks Hengjie, I tried out using the eval function and it is working for me now.